# laravel: how to actually login users (ajax login)

Tags: ajax, laravel, authentication

Can't...Log users... in... Angry.

Basically, I'm running users through the regular login, with my own authenticated method defined to return a json object instead of being redirected. For the moment, I'm returning the results of this function

```
Auth::check();
```

Which returns true when all is said and done. 
The problem is that my logins don't appear to exist beyond this single call. If I make anymore ajax calls, `Auth::check()` fails every time. If I refresh the page, `auth::check()` fails.

Please god help me.

PS. My session driver is current set to cookies.

//EDIT TO SHOW THE PEOPLE I'M NOT CRAZY

```
 public function ajaxLogin(Request $request)
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        return response()
        ->json('loggedIn');
    }

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }


    return response()
    ->json([
            $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}
    protected function authenticated($request, $user){
    Auth::login($user);
    return response()->json( 'yo');
}
```

If I send the right credentials, I get back yo. If I send the right credentials again (another ajax call) I get yo. I can never get logged in.

From what I can tell, for some reason, my sessions are being destroyed with every request? I don't know why, but this does appear to be why I'm never logged in.

//EDIT ADD SITUATIONAL CLARITY

laravel -v 5.2

this is all through the auth controller, so just the default:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Comment: which laravel version are you using? can you also post you  routes.php?

Comment: Which middleware are enabled on your routes you are using?